# Почему в браузере MS EDGE не работает метод addListener

Tags: javascript, браузер, microsoft-edge

В JS использую метод  `addListener`, в браузере MS EDGE в консоле вылетает ошибка:

> "Object doesn't support property or method 'addListener'"

Попробовал использовать полифил - не помогло, в консоле прописываю `console.dir(window.matchMedia('all'));`
выдает такую штуку, якобы эта функция существует:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тут проблема не с функцией, а с тем, куда вы его вешаете. Судя по ошибке - вы пытаетесь повесить слушатель на объект, тогда как(насколько я знаю) вешать этот обработчик можно только на `DOM` элемент. Добавьте свой код в вопрос.

Comment: Вы не показали, у кого именно и в каком контексте вы пытаетесь вызвать addListener. Приведите [mcve]

Comment: @VladSpirin, устаревшая информация и `EDGE & IE11 ` прекрасно поддерживают

Comment: var screen = window.matchMedia('(max-width:999px)');
screen.addListener(changes);

Comment: используйте `addEventListener`, в чём проблема?

Comment: пробовал, тогда в консоле ругается на addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, дело в том что в Edge событие addListener срабатывает после загрузке всего Дом дерева, а в других нормальных браузерах это срабатывает перед загрузкой дом дерева, пришлось добавить конкретное условие под браузер Edge.